# How can I find out the reason of 'request timed out' on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection-timeout

I can't access my website suddenly hosted on AWS EC2. `ping example.com` gets the following result:

```
PING example.com

Pinging example.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

PS: the security group associated with my instance is as follows:

```
Ports   Protocol    Source  launch-wizard-2
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

I can't connect to my instance using ssh as well (can't access log file). All what I can do is to check the EC2 dashboard `aws.amazon.com`. Everything looks fine.

In `Status Checks`,

> System Status Checks  System reachability check passed Instance
>
> Status Checks  Instance reachability check passed

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

**How can I find out the reason?**

PS: the last backup file downloaded to dropbox is `backwpup_b9aba0_2015-07-12_03-03-25.tar.gz`.

---

**EDITT**: Now it works. I guess that the issue is caused by the limitation of CPU credits (`t2.micro`) but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Does your instance have permissions to access the outside internet? Does your security group allow you SSH access for your IP (or from a bastion?)

Comment: Yes. It works perfect before and I haven't made any change in recent days.

Comment: My experience of EC2 instances is that this can just happen sometimes. Try restarting the instance.

Comment: @scrowler  
I reboot my instance but the issue still exists. There is nothing in the system log file after stopping and then starting the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I host an OSQA site under the same instance and dozens of spammers on OSQA keep posting poker-related questions, which consumes almost all CPU credits.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but your [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) (firewall) may not allow ICMP requests? You will probably need to enable icmp traffic for the pings to succeed.  The same goes for SSH.  If port 22 is not open you won't be able to connect.

Comment: I can neither access `example.com`  nor connect to the instance using ssh.

Comment: You need to look in the AWS console under the EC2 dashboard.  Check your instance and see which security group it's using, then look for the "security groups" link on the left of the dashboard. Select the group that your instance uses and see what is allowed under "inbound" traffic.

Comment: Another thought, are you able to connect via the aws / ec2 console?  If you select your instance in the dashboard, at the top there is a "connect" button.  You could also choose "actions > instance settings > get system log" to possibly get more clues as to what's going on.  It's possible the instance crashed and needs to be rebooted.

Comment: the ports allowed for `inbound` traffic is `22, 80, 443`

Comment: For example, try to SSH into your machine and see what the log says, i.e., if it sees you tried to SSH, if it blocked you, or if it just has no idea of your existence.

Comment: I reboot my instance but the issue still exists. There is nothing in the system log file after stopping and then starting the instance.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone, I can't even connect my instance using SSH as descripted in the question.

Comment: Ok, if you can't connect with that connect button and reboot doesn't help, I would have a look here, particularly starting at the section "Start a debug linux instance" - this should help you recover (assuming you are using EBS-backed instance): https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598